# Alternative syntax for ElasticSearch vs ThinkingSphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, thinking-sphinx, tire

Please have a look on below code, Its the normal indexing statement for `thinking sphinx`

```
indexes owned_tags.name, :as => :owned_tag_names
has owned_tags.id, :as => :owned_tag_ids, :facet => true
```

Can any one guide what would be the syntax to have same index in `ElasticSearch` ?

I tried out.

```
tire.mapping do
  indexes :owned_tag_names, type: 'array', analyzer: :ngram_analyzer, index_name: 'tag'
  indexes :owned_tag_ids,   type: 'array'
end

def to_indexed_json
{
    owned_tag_names: owned_tags.collect(&:name),
    owned_tag_ids: owned_tags.collect(&:id)
}.to_json
end
```

and it is giving me the error:

```
400 : {"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [user]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [array] declared on field [owned_tag_ids]]; ","status":400}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `string` type for definining mapping for arrays, as the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type.html) suggests:

```
tire.mapping do
  indexes :owned_tag_names, type: 'string', analyzer: :ngram_analyzer, index_name: 'tag'
  indexes :owned_tag_ids,   type: 'string'
end
```

Note, that you could define the JSON serialization in the `mapping` block with the `as` option:

```
tire.mapping do
  indexes :owned_tag_names,
          type: 'array',
          analyzer: :ngram_analyzer,
          index_name: 'tag',
          as: proc { owned_tags.collect(&:name) }

  indexes :owned_tag_ids,
          type: 'array',
          as: proc { owned_tags.collect(&:id) }
end
```